# Add a horizontal rule under section title without any additional package

Tags: sectioning

I would like to add a horizontal rule under section title, change colour and character of the title. Until now I have been able to change the color and character, but it revealed to me a hard task to add the horizontal rule under the title. What I have done until now is the following:

```
\RequirePackage%
{%
   fontspec,%
   xcolor,%
}
...
...
\definecolor[named]{SectionFontColour}{wave}{395}
\newfontfamily \SectionFont {ITC Avant Garde Gothic}
...
...
\renewcommand\section
{
  \@startsection{section}% #1
  {1}% #2
  {\z@}% #3
  {-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus .2ex}% #4
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}% #5
  {%
     \SectionFont%
     \Large%
     \mdseries%
     \textcolor{SectionFontColour}%
} % #6
```

I would like to accomplish this task in the `\section` macro or in the `\@statrsection` macro. I would not use this way:

```
\let \oldsection \section
\renewcommand \section {\oldsection ... <some code that makes the rule>}
```

neither I would use additional packages here.
And by the way, why the declaration of the `\section` does not take any parameter, when we call this macro (`\section`) we pass an argument to it? So the macro should be declared with a parameter, or not?
Please help me to clarify these questions.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid additional packages and certain approaches? Would you not wish to use them if those were the best strategies?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, and for understand better how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\bfseries\mytitle}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{#1\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\begin{document}
\section{Some section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK! Thank you very much! 
But, for me remains unclear the following:
When we call the macro '\section' we pass an argument to it: '\section{Some section}' so the declaration of this macro should be something like this: '\renewcommand {\section}[1]{<body of the macro>}'. Why there is no need of [1] in declaration?

Comment: @Gela No. The argument you give to `\section` is passed on to `\mytitle` macro. It is implicit here.

Comment: How would I go about removing the number?